# How to animate a sprite sheet/texture regions from 1 corner to touch point in libgdx?

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, libgdx, android-animation

I was developing a game using the Libgdx game library.
I came up with this problem while trying to animate from one corner point to touch point using
libgdx.
Used this tutorial for understanding basics of Libgdx animation basics  [Link](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/2D-Animation).

I am not able to find how animations in libgdx works,Normal movement of frames takes place but how to start single time normal animation upon touch on screen.
Thanks in advance for help.

Edit: 
My class implements Screen
This is what i tried

In class default constructor

```
animation=new Animation(1/15f, atlas1.getRegions());
```

In Render method :-
To check touch

```
public void touched()
{
    if(Gdx.input.isTouched())
    {
        touched = true;
        x = Gdx.input.getX();
        y = Gdx.input.getY();
        velocityX = (x - animationX) / 100;
        velocityY = (y - animationY) / 100;
    }
}
```

After calling touch method For animation

```
public void anim()
{
    if (touched) 
    {
         elapsedTime += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
         //animationX += velocityX;
        // animationY += velocityY;
         batch.draw(animation.getKeyFrame(elapsedTime, false), x, y);
         animfinished=animation.isAnimationFinished(elapsedTime);
     }
    if(touched)
    {
          batch.draw(bullettouch, x, y, bullettouch.getRegionWidth(), bullettouch.getRegionHeight());
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to specify one thing, are you using Scene2D or not? Animation on actors and animation on your own objects is fairly different.

Comment: I am animating different objects which i have stored in pack/png.

Comment: but are you using SpriteBatch or Scene2d and Actors

Comment: i am using SpriteBatch @Zhuinden

Comment: @Zhuinden i have put whatever i tried till now,but the animation is repeating if i put looping true and if i put it to false it repeats at only 1 position.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [InputListener](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/InputListener.html) for touch event and use this to control your animation.

Below is simple approach. Of course, more proper would be to extend Animation class and move there all animation logic.

```
public class AnimationTest implements ApplicationListener, InputListener {

    boolean touched = false;
    Animation animation;
    float elapsedTime = 0;
    float touchedX, touchedY;
    float animationX, animationY;
    float velocityX, velocityY;

    //  ... do not forget to register InputListener here ...

    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer,int button) {
        touched = true;
        touchedX = x;
        touchedY = y;
        velocityX = (touchedX - animationX) / 100;
        velocityY = (touchedY - animationY) / 100;
    }

    // ... 
    
    @Override
    public void render() {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        batch.begin();

        if (touched) {
            elapsedTime += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
            animationX += velocityX;
            animationY += velocityY;
            batch.draw(animation.getKeyFrame(elapsedTime, true), animationX, animationY);
        }
        
        batch.end();
    }

}
```

This is where animation occurs:

`batch.draw(animation.getKeyFrame(elapsedTime, true), animationX , animationY);`

You just gets appropiate keyframe from your animation and draws this on batch.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void anim()
{
    if (touched) 
    {
         elapsedTime += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
         //animationX += velocityX;
        // animationY += velocityY;
         batch.draw(animation.getKeyFrame(elapsedTime, false), x, y);
         animfinished=animation.isAnimationFinished(elapsedTime);
     }
    if(touched)
    {
          batch.draw(bullettouch, x, y, bullettouch.getRegionWidth(), bullettouch.getRegionHeight());
    }
}
```

Comment: A few words of explanation would also be helpful.